# Import Full MySQL Dump

Tags: mysql, sql, import

I have exported a full backup of a database with HeidiSQL 7.

Now when importing it via PHPMyAdmin, I noticed that I MUST select the database `information_schema`, because that's how the DB is exported (Or this is how HeidiSQL 7 exports databases as objects to an SQL file?).

However, that is a problem because when I import (the exported file) with HeidiSQL 7 (instead of PHPMyAdmin), while selecting the `information_schema` database, and clicking on Import SQL file (from the tools menu), it says that access is denied for the root user.

In PHPMyAdmin, the option to import is not available when selecting the database `information_schema`.

How do I import my full database dump? (This is how I exported it: HeidiSQL > export database **objects** to SQL file)

Edit:
I tried it with the command line, but without luck:

```
C:\Programs\XAMPP\mysql\bin>mysql --verbose --user=root Information_schema < DT.
sql
--------------
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */
--------------

--------------
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */
--------------

--------------
/*!40014 SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */
--------------

--------------
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `CHARACTER_SETS` DISABLE KEYS */
--------------

ERROR 1044 (42000) at line 13: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' to data
base 'information_schema'

C:\Programs\XAMPP\mysql\bin>
```

This is a snippet of the SQL file:
http://pastebin.com/6hwhK2CJ

Note: The password for my root user is blank.

Maybe another solution for my problem:
How do I import only the database I want, from the SQL file? For example a database with the name "Employees"? Because that SQL file should contain a few databases.

Edit2:
(answer to first comment)
I downloaded MySQL Workbench, setup the connection...

```
03:23:08 Restoring C:\Files\DB.sql

Running: mysql.exe --defaults-extra-file="c:\files\temp\tmplnjwd6.cnf"  --host=localhost --user=root --port=3306 --default-character-set=utf8 --comments < "C:\\Files\\DB.sql"

ERROR 1046 (3D000) at line 13: No database selected


Operation failed with exitcode 1

03:23:08 Import of C:\Files\DB.sql has finished with 1 errors
```

Comment: Install MySQL workbench. All the dumps and imports are no brainer then. Also check in mysql.user table if the password for root is blank for all instances of root in that table

Comment: Try to add a USE <database_name> statement at the beginning of the dump file.

Comment: About the first error with Information_schema - you cannot modify this database, because it is system and readonly.

Comment: You just have to remove all the "information_schema" queries from your dump and try again. I'm curious why you use full dump instead simple DB dump?

Comment: I saw the information_schema contains some info about other databases, will the other DB's be unnafected? :o and is there any tool for doing this (if yes please tell how-to)? The SQL file is 9 mb, it's not easy to edit it with, for example, NotePad Pro.

Comment: also I selected everything just because I was in a hurry ; p

Comment: @GamErix I recommend using `mysqldump [database_name] > mydump.sql` to dump data. Always prefer built-in (or bundled) features over external tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`INFORMATION_SCHEMA` is a pseudo, read-only database (in fact, it is an "[ANSI standard set of read-only views](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_schema)").

You need to remove all dump data related to this pseudo database, as there is absolutely no way to import it.

[Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/download/v6.1.3.html) is able to easily handle a 9 MB file, and also provides nice syntax highlighting.

Comment: So I need to edit the sql file manually anyway? :( BTW It's not that NoteTab pro loads the file slow.. It can load files fast which are even 2 gb big.

Comment: @Gam Erix Did you dump all tables from all databases in one single file ? If yes, search for the `USE` keyword. Do you find any line like `USE db_name` ?

Comment: Ah well I edited it manually, It was a pain, but it finally worked. Thanks.